# Which book Cole reads in the last episode of the "Tales From the Loop" series?

Tags: tales-from-the-loop

The series in its last episode ("Home") shows us little boy Cole being given a book nearly at the beginning of the episode. I've got a strong feeling this book is H. G. Wells' *The Time Machine*, but after watching the episode till the end I found no direct evidence of this.

Can you see something in the story that supports this or otherwise gives any clues of which book that one might be?